How to add an external URL to the proxy
I am having an issue with a test run being stuck via a GitLab pipeline, though it does work when I run my test locally. I have found the common issue which is it gets stuck when trying to call an external URL.
Example url: https://api.us.cajama.com/v3.6
From what I have heard, it might need to be added to the proxy, but I am not sure how to do that. Can someone direct me in adding this URL to the proxy so GitGab have access to this external service?
Is it a change in the gitlab-ci.yml file or something else?

Please don't re-post. It's less about the config of a specific pipeline, more about the connectivity of the runner (public? Self-hosted? ...?) itself.

with a test run What is a "test run"? What is tested? What does it mean? What is being executed? What command? What is it doing? being stuck How do you know it is "stuck"? What do you experience , what do you "see", that suggests that it is "stuck"? I have found the common issue How did you "found" it? to be added to the proxy From whom did you hear? What did you hear exactly? What does it mean to "add it to the proxy"? Which proxy? What is the proxy running? Where is the proxy running? Who manages the proxy? Did you ask for clarification the person you heard it from?

You need to configure your proxy settings
Add your environment variable to gitlab-ci.yml
variables:
  http_proxy: http://your-proxy-server:proxy-port
  https_proxy: http://your-proxy-server:proxy-port
  no_proxy: "localhost,127.0.0.1,api.us.cajama.com"

Add this proxy settings to your job that requires access to the external URL
stages:
  - test
    test-job:
      stage: test
      script:
        - echo "Running tests"
        - export http_proxy="http://your-proxy-server:proxy-port"
        - export https_proxy="http://your-proxy-server:proxy-port"
        - export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,api.us.cajama.com"
        - your-test-command

You can fill the placeholders with your own record
